# using new WP_Query in save_post function alters $post

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, loop, save-post

I'm trying to include a WP_Query in a save_post function for a custom post type. The query is used to check all the other posts for a custom field `bh_shortcode` to make sure the content of the field is not duplicated.

However, when I create and loop through the wp_query, the value of `$post` changes, and one of the post entires that appears in the results of the wp_query is then set to `$post`, and as a result, all the fields are then saved to the wrong post (rather than the one I have open).

The `wp_reset_query()` doesn't appear to have any effect.

How can I correct this?

```
function save_bhour_details(){
    global $post;

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
        return;
    }

    if ( get_post_type($post) != 'bhours'){
        return;
    }

    //validate shortcode
    $bh_shortcode='';
    $error_shortcode_empty=false;
    $error_shortcode_duplicate=false;


    if(isset($_POST['bh_shortcode']) && !empty($_POST['bh_shortcode'])){
        $bh_shortcode=bh_strip_special_chars($_POST['bh_shortcode']);

        if(empty($bh_shortcode)){
            $error_shortcode_empty=true;
        }
        else{

            $query_validate = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type'=>'bhours',
            ));

            while($query_validate->have_posts()){
                $query_validate->the_post();
                $bh_post_shortcode=array_shift(get_post_custom_values('bh_shortcode'));

                if($bh_post_shortcode==$bh_shortcode){
                    $error_shortcode_duplicate=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            wp_reset_query();           
        }

    }
    else{
        $error_shortcode_empty=true;
    }

    if(!$error_shortcode_empty && !$error_shortcode_duplicate){
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'bh_shortcode', $bh_shortcode);
    }
    else{
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'bh_shortcode', '');
    }

}
add_action('save_post', 'save_bhour_details');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `wp_reset_query()` and `wp_reset_post()` didn't appear to do anything in this situation, here's something that seems to work. I'm not entirely sure if this is the accepted approach, but I got it working by temporarily storing the $post value before the WP_Query, then setting it back to the $post variable after the query was complete.

```
$currentpost = $post;

$query = new WP_Query(/* ... */);

while($query->have_posts()){
     $query->the_post();
     //do stuff
}

$post = $currentpost;
```

Comment: `wp_reset_post()` won't work because it resets the global `$post` to whatever is stored in the `$wp_query`. On `save_post`, WordPress doesn't use store the post beings saved in side `$wp_query` (in fact its not using it all). Thus when you 'reset' the post, you are probably resetting it to the first post in your query.

Comment: For your use case, I would use `get_posts()` and pass the post ID where needed - and not touch the global `$post`. This would actually be more efficient too.

Comment: @StephenHarris how would I retrieve the post ID withing the `have_posts()` while loop without touching `$post`?

Comment: Each object in the array returned by `get_posts()` has the property ID. E.g. `foreach( get_posts() as $bhour){ echo $bhour->ID;}`